# Indirect speech about context

Tags: grammar

Listening to a song, I've met one interesting sentence with indirect speech, but it's a song. An author can use whatever words he needs to get into rhyme, so I want to ask if this is right to write like in that case. There're two examples (the first one was in the song, the second one is that how I think would have been right):

> So I said this is the worst day of my life.
>
> So I said it was the worst day of my life.

As I believe, this is right to use one tense back (didn't know how to say it more appropriately, but I hope you understand what I meant) when we have something to do with an indirect speech, although there're always exceptions of any rule, and we have to work with context. I reckon the first example isn't that bad if we're speaking about the day that isn't over yet. However, anyone can be mistaken.

And, please, accept my apologies for my non-grammatical speech.

Comment: You are correct. It's called "backshifting" of tenses for reported speech. (I would use *that* — not *it* — for *this* in the reported version.) But the song, as you said, can do what it wants, including leaving the punctuation out of a direct quote like  *So I said: "This is the worst day of my life."*

Comment: But, also, this is contradictory: "*An author can use whatever words he needs to get into rhyme, so I want to ask if this is right to write like in that case.*" You can't say it's up to the author, and then immediately follow that by asking if the author is right.

Comment: Yes and if this is from a song, how can we know what punctuation the writer put on "So I said this is the worst day of my life" ?

Comment: Thank y'all, I guess I got it!